# Web 8.5 doesn't allow multiple deployer listening to the same activeMQ

Tags: deployer, web8.5, microservices

Looks like in web8.5 does not support multiple deployer instance listening to same instance of ActiveMQ with different Topics, when I publish with second deployer, I am getting below error..  Any suggestion??

*Error creating bean with name 'cacheConfigurationLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to construct CacheChannel
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.SpringContentDeliveryKernel.ensureInitialised(SpringContentDeliveryKernel.java:38)
    at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.registerKernel(KernelFactory.java:40)
    at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.getKernel(KernelFactory.java:27)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getComponent(StorageManagerFactory.java:70)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getStorageManager(StorageManagerFactory.java:49)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:175)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:121)
    at com.tridion.storage.deploy.PageHandler.deploy(PageHandler.java:64)
    at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:101)
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processPage(PageDeploy.java:151)
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processItem(PageDeploy.java:118)
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:74)
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:78)
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:51)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionDeployerStepAdapter.process(TridionDeployerStepAdapter.java:91)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$execute(StepActor.scala:60)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:44)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:27)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to construct CacheChannel
    at com.tridion.cache.CacheChannel.createCacheChannel(CacheChannel.java:232)
    at com.tridion.cache.CacheFactory.configure(CacheFactory.java:222)
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.CacheConfigurationLoader.configure(CacheConfigurationLoader.java:41)
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.CacheConfigurationLoader.initialize(CacheConfigurationLoader.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 0; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.(Unknown Source)
    at com.tridion.cache.CacheChannel.(CacheChannel.java:219)
    at com.tridion.cache.CacheChannel.createCacheChannel(CacheChannel.java:229)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind*

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever resolve this issue?